# Munkres exercise 13.1

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve the following exercise.

> Let $X$ be a topological space; let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Suppose that for each $x \in A$ there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U \subset A$. Show that $A$ is open in $X$.

Here is my attempt.

> Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for the topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$. Fix $a \in A$. By assumption, there is an open set $U \owns x$ such that $U \subset A$. As $U \in \mathcal{T}$ and $x \in U$, there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subset U$, but $U \subset A$, so we have $x \in B \subset A$. Therefore, $A$ is open.

How does this look? Is it ok to just "pick" a basis?

Comment: There is no need to involve a basis. Use the provided information to show that $A$ is the union of open sets.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4349170

Comment: @angryavian Though I understand the proof given below, is the proof involving a basis incorrect?

Comment: A proof containing an unnecessary feature (using a base) is worse than a direct proof from first principles, is what the others are saying. Go for the simplest proof, the more indirect proof is not incorrect per se, but inferior.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok, but the proof wasn't incorrect? That's all I'm interested in knowing, as my intuition led me to that proof. I fully accept that another proof is easier/superior, but I just want to be sure I didn't make a mathematical error.

Comment: You could just pick the basis that is equal to the topology itself. So there always is a trivial basis. Plus you have to justify the steps with propositions from the text.

Comment: I could've been more specific surely on the basis by saying let $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{T}$. Other than that, I believe I only used the assumption in the problem and the definition of what it means to be open in the topology generated by a basis.